# Python PIR sensor loop works until writing to MySQL

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, mysql-python, sensors, raspberry-pi4

I am an experienced developer but new to Raspberry Pis and python.

I have connected a Pi to a motion sensor and picked up a infinite loop script that checks whether the Pi sees something "now" or not and returns 0 or 1.

I modified the script to write when that 0 or 1 changes to a mysql record. Script below.

This worked fine for a short time. Now something odd has happened. When it is run, it switches from 0 to 1 seemingly randomly, until I take out the writes to the MySQL DB. So if I remove the lines that "dbcur.execute(sql)" and "dbconnection.commit()" from the code it works perfectly (mostly 0 and then 1 for the short time i sees something), but when I add them back it, it returns to randomly and quickly switching between 0 and 1 regardless of the sensor.

This is driving me mad and I've tried reinstalling the whole OS on the Pi again and installing everything but it still does it! Help!

```
    import mysql.connector
    import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
    import time
    import datetime
    from core import Core
    core=Core()

    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
    PIR_PIN = core.gpio
    GPIO.setup(PIR_PIN, GPIO.IN)

    try:
         print "PIR Module Test (CTRL+C to exit)"
         time.sleep(2)
         print "Ready"
         lastval=999;
         cursensorlogid=-1
         dbconnection = core.getDB()
         dbcur = dbconnection.cursor()
         while True:
              nowval=GPIO.input(PIR_PIN)
              if(nowval!=lastval):
                   lastval=nowval
                   logstart=datetime.datetime.now()-datetime.timedelta(seconds=core.logseconds)
                   sql = "delete from sensorlog where `start`<'{}';"
                   sql = sql.format(logstart.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
                   sql = "insert into sensorlog (`val`,`start`,`end`,`init`) values ({},'{}','{}',{});"
                   sql = sql.format(nowval,datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'),datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'),1 if lastval==999 else 0)
                   dbcur.execute(sql)
                   dbconnection.commit()
                   print "Changed to "+str(nowval)+" - "+time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
              time.sleep(0.2)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
         print "Quit"
         GPIO.cleanup()
```

Comment: I assume you are talking about HC-SR501. be sure to power it with at least 5v. If you connect it to 3.3v it will provide you with random data.

Comment: Thanks Maxim - turns out they had put the voltage wrongly and it now works. I can see writing to the database would pull some power from in the Pi, but seems odd what happened from the voltage of the sensor... anyway - thanks!